# Are there any Windows programs to resize partitions?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, diskpart

Are there some applications that are embedded in Windows (such as diskpart) to resize partitions?

Comment: Disk management or Diskpart is all there is, diskpart being the most powerful if you know how to use it.

Comment: Without the "embedded in Windows" qualification, which people are reading as "ships in the box with Windows", this question would actually match its title, and there would be more programs listed in the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can manage disks using the Disk Management tool (found under Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Disk Management)

Comment: There is limit if you use this tool on large HDD.

Comment: I recently used Disk Mgmt to extend a partition into free space on a drive.  I don't know if it is capable of shrinking a volume.

Comment: I believe so:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx

Comment: that page only mentions shrinking, do you know if it can increase then size of it?  does that involve dynamic disks? 'cos is it still NTFS when MS does it? 'cos i've read http://www.petri.co.il/difference_between_basic_and_dynamic_disks_in_windows_xp_2000_2003.htm

Answer (score 4):

I would not use the Microsoft Disk Management tool. I am not a fan of Microsoft's Dynamic disks.

I would use a 3rd party tool. I personally have a number of them dating back a long time, including Partition Magic and Acronis Disk Director. A very popular and easy-to-use option is the home edition of Easeus: http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/comparison.html .

http://download.cnet.com/Easeus-Partition-Master-Home-Edition/3000-2248_4-10863346.html

Answer (score 3):

I know that Paragon Partition Manager is popular. There is a free edition, but I think it might be somewhat limited...

However, I normally use the GParted Live CD: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Answer (score 3):

I find the most powerful solution is to download gParted (which is free) and run the LiveCD on your computer. However, you have to be very careful that you don't resize anything too small or delete partitions that you require to run Windows. Since it gets full access to the hard drive, you can do anything, but you also can seriously mess things up if you don't be careful.

Answer (score 2):

Disk Management is the closest built in software.

Answer (score 1):

I just used Easeus Partition Manager. It does the task that i needed. Thanks